# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kedro.versioning'

Tags: kedro, cookiecutter

i have upgraded my kedro to latest version.But i have used kedro.versioning in my project.And latest kedro has no module of this name.Can anyone please suggest anything

Answer (score 0):

this was removed in 0.18.x what are you trying to retrieve we can think of a workaround?

Comment: I have imported Journal from this module in my project. Can you suggest something about what can i use instead of it

Comment: So the journal was removed in 0.18.x what were you doing with it?